# How to update object in local storage in vue js?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2, local-storage

I have user data in this formate in local storage which I am storing at the time of login.

```
{id: 17, name: "Boss  original", email: "boss2@gmail.com", email_verified_at: null, fcm_token: "c_jxurpcQY6Qdeh0b9ZQIV:APA91bH4BKd-dIkN5N7jtv52ZH5…zUzd35AGdNIPmn1uUSMcU_oKgnO2eAM8xybXM7MJzanzFvmZH", …}
admin: 1
allowed_login: 1
api_token: null
created_at: "2021-04-07T09:08:32.000000Z"
customer_id: null

is_driver: 0
location_access: 0
name: "Boss  original"
notification: 1
online: 0
phone_number: "12345678912"
photo: "1617894632.jpg"
role_data: {id: 3, staff_id: 17, address: "Cuernavaca, Morelos, Mexico", latitude: "18.9242095", longitude: "-99.22156590000002", …}
role_id: 9
social_security_number: "1238"
status: 1
unread_notifications: [{…}]
updated_at: "2021-04-18T16:46:32.000000Z"
warehouse: null
```

In this object i need to update the property  `unread_notifications: [{…}]`

How i can update that property?
I can get this object like this

```
localStorage.getItem(USER_INFO);
```

and can store like this

```
localStorage.setItem(USER_INFO, userData);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can store data like this.

```
localStorage.setItem(USER_INFO, JSON.stringify(userData));
```

You can read, update and store again.

```
const userData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(USER_INFO));
userData.unread_notifications = ...
localStorage.setItem(USER_INFO, JSON.stringify(userData));
```

Comment: for example if i have one variable `notifications` . then how to update  `userData.unread_notifications`?